# Command line start ssms with localdb does not work

Tags: ssms

I have a requirement to start ssms (SQL Management Studio) from the command line that connects to a (localdb)\myinstance. The instance exists

```
sqllocaldb info myinstance
```

but using the command line and the -S parameter with (localdb)\myinstance throws an error.

```
PS C:\workingArea> ssms -S(localdb)\myinstance
localdb : The term 'localdb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:9
+ ssms -S(localdb)\myinstance
```

I can connect using the named pipe but would ideally like to use the known name.

Comment: Do you have to share the instance? The only other thing I have found is something about `(localdb)\.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following: `ssms -S LOCALHOST\myinstance`to connect to a LocalDb instance

Comment: No that did not work, I also tried .\myinstance, I wonder if its something todo with the ssms command line args not accepting (localdb).